# CSS Responsive table - problem with height

Tags: html, css

few weeks ago I saw a simple, interesting list on codepen but unfortunately it was not resposnive.

I try to make that list responsive on my site for friend.
http://damianobajtek.pl/LandingAdamv2/ (Menu -> services).

I cannot resolve problem with height with media queries. I know that my div is too small (100vh) but what should I do to make it responsive?

Probably the simplest solution could be flexbox but I have a problem to remake that list on flexbox.

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: You should not be mixing flexbox with floats. As well, flex will apply to direct child (in that case, only the UL, making no difference). You can also consider grid layout

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  Please read [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem within the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes here:

```
.second_services .content {
  /* float: left; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.second_services .content li {
  /* float: left; */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-left: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
  /* width: 33.2%; */
  flex: 1 1 calc(100% / 3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 25%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Colors Hover */
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .second_services .content li {
    /* width: 50%; */
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}
```

```css
/* STYLE FOR SERVICES */

.second_services html,
.second_services body,
.second_services div,
.second_services h1,
.second_services h2,
.second_services h3,
.second_services h4,
.second_services h5,
.second_services h6,
.second_services p,
.second_services ol,
.second_services ul,
.second_services li,
.second_services footer,
.second_services header,
.second_services hgroup,
.second_services menu,
.second_services nav,
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.second_services html {
  line-height: 1;
}

.second_services ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.second_services table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.second_services caption,
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.second_services q,
.second_services blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}

.second_services q:before,
.second_services q:after,
.second_services blockquote:before,
.second_services blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

.second_services a img {
  border: none;
}

.second_services article,
.second_services aside,
.second_services details,
.second_services figcaption,
.second_services figure,
.second_services footer,
.second_services header,
.second_services hgroup,
.second_services menu,
.second_services nav,
.second_services section,
.second_services summary {
  display: block;
}


/**
*
* Animate.css
* From : https://daneden.me/animate/
*
**/

.second_services .animated {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.second_services .animated.hinge {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
  -o-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  70% {
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.bounceIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
  -moz-animation-name: bounceIn;
  -o-animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    -o-transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.second_services .bounceInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
  -moz-animation-name: bounceInUp;
  -o-animation-name: bounceInUp;
  animation-name: bounceInUp;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateY(-2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    -o-transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.second_services .bounceInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
  -moz-animation-name: bounceInDown;
  -o-animation-name: bounceInDown;
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  80% {
    -o-transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.second_services .bounceInLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
  -moz-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
  -o-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
  animation-name: bounceInLeft;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(10px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateX(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateX(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    -o-transform: translateX(10px);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.second_services .bounceInRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInRight;
  -moz-animation-name: bounceInRight;
  -o-animation-name: bounceInRight;
  animation-name: bounceInRight;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-200deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateIn {
  0% {
    -moz-transform-origin: center center;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-200deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform-origin: center center;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotateIn {
  0% {
    -o-transform-origin: center center;
    -o-transform: rotate(-200deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform-origin: center center;
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateIn {
  0% {
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: rotate(-200deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.rotateIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotateIn;
  -moz-animation-name: rotateIn;
  -o-animation-name: rotateIn;
  animation-name: rotateIn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateInUpLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateInUpLeft {
  0% {
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotateInUpLeft {
  0% {
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateInUpLeft {
  0% {
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.second_services .rotateInUpLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotateInUpLeft;
  -moz-animation-name: rotateInUpLeft;
  -o-animation-name: rotateInUpLeft;
  animation-name: rotateInUpLeft;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateInDownLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateInDownLeft {
  0% {
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotateInDownLeft {
  0% {
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateInDownLeft {
  0% {
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.second_services .rotateInDownLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotateInDownLeft;
  -moz-animation-name: rotateInDownLeft;
  -o-animation-name: rotateInDownLeft;
  animation-name: rotateInDownLeft;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateInUpRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateInUpRight {
  0% {
    -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotateInUpRight {
  0% {
    -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateInUpRight {
  0% {
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.second_services .rotateInUpRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotateInUpRight;
  -moz-animation-name: rotateInUpRight;
  -o-animation-name: rotateInUpRight;
  animation-name: rotateInUpRight;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateInDownRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateInDownRight {
  0% {
    -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotateInDownRight {
  0% {
    -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateInDownRight {
  0% {
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.second_services .rotateInDownRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotateInDownRight;
  -moz-animation-name: rotateInDownRight;
  -o-animation-name: rotateInDownRight;
  animation-name: rotateInDownRight;
}

.second_services {
  background: #31486f;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}


/**
*
* Responsive list
*
**/

.second_services {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 100vh;
}

.second_services .responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.second_services .content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.second_services .content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 101%;
}

.second_services .content li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-left: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
  flex: 1 1 calc(100% / 3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 25%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Colors Hover */
}

.content li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content li:hover .card-front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(50deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(50deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(50deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(50deg);
  transform: rotateX(50deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(50deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(50deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(50deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(50deg);
  transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(50deg);
}

.content li:hover .card-back {
  z-index: 950;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0deg);
}

.content li:nth-child(n) .card-back {
  background: #bea34d;
}

.content li:nth-child(1) h2,
.content li:nth-child(2) h2,
.content li:nth-child(3) h2 {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.content .card-front,
.content .card-back {
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 400ms;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 400ms;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 400ms;
  transition: transform 400ms;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.content .card-front {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0);
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0);
  -ms-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0);
  -o-transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0);
  transform: perspective(1000) rotateX(0);
  z-index: 900;
}

.content .card-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  z-index: 800;
}

.content h2 {
  font-size: 2vw;
  ;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.content h2 b {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.content p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.second_services .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #31486f;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-top: 3%;
}

.second_services .active {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

.active .all-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.active .all-content h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/*
@media (min-width: 1366px)
{
.second_services .close {  
    margin-top: 3%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 440px) and (max-width: 750px) {
    .second_services .content h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .second_services .content p {
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    .second_services .content li {
        width: 33.1%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 439px) {
    .second_services .content h2 {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .second_services .content p {
        font-size: 13px;
    }

   .second_services .content li {
        width: 33%;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 450px) {
    .second_services .content h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .second_services .content h2 b {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .second_services .content li {
        width: 33%;
    }
}

*/

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .content p {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .second_services .content li {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 439px) {
  .content h2 {
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
  .second_services .content p {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .second_services .content li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="second_services" id="second_services">
  <div class="responsive">
    <ul class="content">

      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>One front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>One back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Pomagamy na każdym etapie prowadzenia działalności. Doradzamy przy wyborze formy prawnej, załatwiamy wszystkie formalności związane z utworzeniem i rejestracją nowego podmiotu, pomagamy zorganizować Twoją działalność w zgodzie z obowiązującym
            prawem.<br><br> Na kolejnym etapie dbamy o Twój komfort i bezpieczeństwo zapewniając skuteczne rozwiązania prawne dostosowane do Twoich potrzeb. Wykwalifikowany i doświadczony zespół pozwoli Ci zająć się tym co dla Ciebie najważniejsze - rozwijaniem
            swojej działalności, bez potrzeby obawiania się o konsekwencje prawne swoich biznesowych decyzji.</h1>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Two front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Two back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Prawo rodzinne</h1>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Three front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Three back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>In vulputate sem a arcu semper</h1>
        </div>
      </li>


      <!-- 2 -->
      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Four front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Four back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Etiam quis sapien interdum</h1>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Five front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Five back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Vivamus metus massa</h1>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Six front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Six back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Integer consequat vitae</h1>
        </div>
      </li>


      <!-- 3 -->
      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Seven front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Seven back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Duis tellus dui vehicula</h1>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Eight front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Eight back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Ligula nulla tempus sem</h1>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Nine fron</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Nine back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Class aptent taciti sociosqu</h1>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Ten front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Ten back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Class aptent taciti sociosqu</h1>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Eleven front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Eleven back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Class aptent taciti sociosqu</h1>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="card-front">
          <h2><b>Twelve front</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
          <h2><b>Twelve back</b></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="all-content" style="display: none;">
          <h1>Class aptent taciti sociosqu</h1>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to not mix flexbox with floats. You could also consider grid layout. Keeping your current html structure, I would do the following for minimal changes (see comments in css):

```
#second_services div.second_services {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    /* height: 100vh; Remove this*/
    background: #31486f;
    color: #fff;
}

.second_services .content {
    /* float: left; Remove this */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* Add the following three lines */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.second_services .content li {
    /* float: left; Remove this */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
    border-left: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
    width: 33.2%;
    height: 250px; /* Define a height: Could be with media queries */
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```